# How to configure caching in Spring Boot such that it doesn't cache errors such as error code 500/401/403

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, caching

In my Spring Boot application, 500 error being cached once it occurs.
This is how I configured in my code:

`response.setHeader("Cache-Control","max-age="+maxAge);`

Is there a way to configure caching in such a way that API end point is hit again rather than displaying 500 error from the cache?

Comment: Cache-Control is mainly for browsers, the browser first check in its cache whether there is a valid response for the url (valid == request is young enough and other rules mentioned here : https://developer.mozilla.org/he/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cache-Control ) - as mentioned here, I think that a combination of stale-if-error and must-revalidate will do the job.

Comment: @planben 
Thank you for the tip. So, I guess this does the job?
`response.setHeader("Cache-Control","stale-if-error=0","must-revalidate=true","max-age="+maxAge);`

Comment: I am not sure regarding stale-while-revalidate but I guess that you read the article - so please share your results.